# Using ack to search for regex in a specific file type

Tags: ack

Wondering if there's a way to look for something like `ack foo "*.scss"`

Comment: Not sure about `ack`, but my go-to tools for such a task would be `grep`, followed possibly by `find` if there are a lot of nested folders we're going through.

Answer (score 0):

Generally ack uses predefined file types, so the pessimistic answer is "No".  However, if you regularly search in .scss files, you may want to set it as a file type in your .ackrc by adding the following line:

```
--type-set=sassy=.scss
```

Answer (score 0):

`"*.scss"` isn't a regex, but shell globbing.

Like voyager42 says about, use

```
--type-set=sassy=.scss
```

in your .ackrc and then you can do

```
ack foo --sassy
```

or if you do NOT want to search sassy files

```
ack foo --nosassy
```